# Getting all rows in the GridControl when using PLinqInstantFeedbackSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I am using `PLinqInstantFeedbackSource` when populating the grid.

```
PLinqInstantFeedbackSource pLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource = new PLinqInstantFeedbackSource();
pLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource.GetEnumerable += pLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource_GetEnumerable;

gridControl.ItemsSource = pLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource;

gridControl.DataContext = SomeViewModel;

private void pLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource_GetEnumerable(object sender, DevExpress.Data.PLinq.GetEnumerableEventArgs e)
{
    e.Source = SomeViewModel.GetList();
}
```

So when i select all rows using:

```
((DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TableView)gridControl.View).SelectAll();​
```

it seems to select all the rows. ​So this is working fine, but the user has not scrolled down so that all the rows are visible or fetched.

So now i want to loop through all the rows and get the row object using:

```
var selectedRowHandles = ((DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TableView)gridControl.View).GetSelectedRowHandles().AsEnumerable();

foreach (var item in selectedRowHandles)
{
    SomeViewModel.SelectedItems.Add((SomeEntityObject)gridControl.GetRow(item)); 
}
```

This seems to work fine for all visible rows, but when it tries to Get the next row that is not visible it throws an exception:

```
​InvalidCastException
Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.Data.NotLoadedObject' to type 'SomeEntityObject'.​
```

So, how to get all rows in the GridControl when using PLinqInstantFeedbackSource when row is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right answer from [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q459086).

Answer (score 1):

The LinqInstantFeedBackSource loads the records from the server into the grid in a seperate thread. If you try to access a row in the grid where the corresponding record is not allready loaded, the source returns an object of the `NotLoadedObject` type. Since the loading of records goes on in the background you can just repeat querying the row until you get your "real" data.

```
foreach (var item in selectedRowHandles)
{
    while (gridControl.GetRow(item) is NotLoadedObject)
    {
             Application.DoEvents();
     }
    SomeViewModel.SelectedItems.Add((SomeEntityObject)gridControl.GetRow(item)); 
}
```